# How to startDrag() a Bitmap?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I've loaded some images to my swf, but I can't make them start dragging, startDrag() works only on a Sprite or MovieClip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitmap Object hasn't got some eventListeners which Sprites and MovieClips have. So i think you should do it like that:

```
    var bitmap_Object:Bitmap;
    var container_sprite:Sprite = new Sprite;

    stage.addChild(container_sprite);
    container_sprite.addChild(bitmap_Object);
    container_sprite.startDrag();
```

Comment: It is not that Bitmap "hasn't got some eventListeners", it's because Bitmap does not inherit from EventDispatcher. Sprite and MovieClip both inherit from EventDispather.